# Latest polkodotjs.org does not connects to Pirl Coin (substrate 2) network

Tags: substrate, polkadot

## Can you inspect and explain the problem not to get error?

### This is Pirl Source Code

> https://github.com/pirl/pirl-2_0
> (at v0.8.25-ad031f3)

### This is pirl polkadotjs.org clone at version at (api v2.2.2-2 ,apps v0.62.2-2 check right top at link)

> https://dashboard.pirl.network/
> custom endpoint: **wss://rpc.pirl.network**

### When i try to transfer coins i got this error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Pirl has their own (now stale and seemingly unmaintained) fork of the Polkadot UI:
https://github.com/pirl

I would recommend using their own products and also read their docs that detail how to use it properly.

EDIT: Looks like there is a solution here https://github.com/paritytech/subport/issues/139

Answer (score 0):

it worked after i set the custom type json (julien, @masterdubs, pirl coin developer, have given me this json

{
"Address": "AccountId",
"LookupSource": "AccountId",
"Account": {
"nonce": "U256",
"balance": "U256"
},
"Transaction": {
"nonce": "U256",
"action": "String",
"gas_price": "u64",
"gas_limit": "u64",
"value": "U256",
"input": "Vec",
"signature": "Signature"
},
"Signature": {
"v": "u64",
"r": "H256",
"s": "H256"
},
"Keys": "SessionKeys5"
}